# Area bounded by a region questions

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the region in the plane bounded by the graph of the function $f(x) = x^2$ , the line $y = 1$, and the lines $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ .

(a) Draw the region $R$ .

(b) Find the area of the region $R$ .

Integrate $x^2$ from $1$ to $2$? But then how do we take a way the region $y=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region $R$ is simply the portion of the graph horizontally between $x=1$ and $x=2$ and vertically less than $f(x)=x^2$ while greater than $y=1$.

The area of region R can be determined with this integral:

$$\int_{1}^{2}f(x)-1\mbox{  }dx$$

Because the area is bounded on the top by $f(x)$ and on the bottom by $y=1$, you "take away" the region where $y<1$ by subtracting it from the area under $f(x)$. Basically, this is a question about the area between two curves.

Comment: Do you mean vertically less than 1?

Comment: by f(x) do you mean x^2?

Comment: Oh shoot i get it now
f(x) = y = x2 and g(x) = y = 1 take away f(x) - g(x) between 1 and 2!

Comment: The integral you provided works out  only the area above y=1?

shouldn't it be more like " integrand of x^2 between 1 to 2" minus "integrand of x^2 - 1" between 1 and 2?

Comment: The more general integral would be the integrating from the lower x bound to the upper x bound of the f(x) - g(x) where f(x) is the upper boundary in the y direction and g(x) is the lower boundary in the y direction. In this case, the upper y bound is the function f(x) and the lower y bound is the line y=1. So, the integrand is f(x)-1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks for the space between $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=y$, bounded by $x=1$ and $x=2$. In between $x=1$ and $x=2$, you'll find that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ such that $1<x<2$. That's the region we're looking for: R.

Set up your integral accordingly:

$$Area =\int_{1}^{2}(f(x)-g(x))\mbox{  }dx$$
$$Area =\int_{1}^{2}(x^2-1)\mbox{  }dx$$
$$Area = \frac{1}{3}x^3-x,$$

Where $x_1=1, x_2=2$:

$$Area = (\frac{1}{3}(2)^3-(2))-(\frac{1}{3}(1)^3-(1)) = \frac{4}{3}$$